# Backtrace through Needleman Wunsch table

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

I'm trying to do a back trace through a completed DP table. Assume that the table is correctly filled in with the proper values.. I can post a snippet of the table if one would like. 
But here is a snippet of my code that generates the strings from the backtrace

```
def stringBuilder(array, xLine, yLine):        
     StringA, StringB = "", ""
     i, j = len(xLine), len(yLine)
     minCost = array[i][j]
     while (i != 0 and j != 0):
        minCost = min(array[i - 1][j], array[i][j - 1], array[i - 1][j- 1])
        if (minCost == array[i - 1][j - 1]):
           StringA += xLine[i - 1]
           StringB += yLine[j - 1]
           array[i - 1][j - 1] = 0
           i -= 1
           j -= 1
        elif (minCost == array[i][j - 1]):
           StringA += '-'
           StringB += yLine[j - 1]
           array[i][j - 1] = 0
           j -= 1
        elif (minCost == array[i - 1][j]):
           StringA += xLine[i - 1]
           StringB += '-'
           array[i - 1][j]= 0
           i -= 1
```

My logic is that it always look through the table and find the smallest value trying to get back to the cost of 0 section of the table. At which i & j should be 0 and the loop exits. Whats special about the NW algorithm is that the values for a gap, deletion, swap can be any number they want, Not just -1, 0 etc

According to a script that checks the back trace, I am wrong. Although I know that I am filling the table correctly as another testing script confirms that.

Comment: Hi again, could the issue be that there are multiple neighbouring squares with the same `minCost`? If this is thje case, your final alignment would be different depending on what order you check via the if statements

Comment: Is the problem simply that you are generating the strings in reverse?  If so, then add StringA=StringA[::-1] and StringB=StringB[::-1]

Comment: Thank you again nbryans, I fiddled around with the order and how the loop terminated and figured it out on my own. But for what it is worth, I didn't include it, but I did flip the strings at the end. I posted the solution down below

Answer (score 1):

If the costs for different actions are different, then your code for filling in the array will look something like:

```
minCost = min(array[i - 1][j]+C0, array[i][j - 1]+C1, array[i - 1][j- 1]+C2)
```

where C0,C1,C2 are the different costs.

In this case, the backtracking code also needs to incorporate these costs as follows:

```
    if (minCost == array[i - 1][j - 1]+C2):
       StringA += xLine[i - 1]
       StringB += yLine[j - 1]
       array[i - 1][j - 1] = 0
       i -= 1
       j -= 1
    elif (minCost == array[i][j - 1]+C1):
       StringA += '-'
       StringB += yLine[j - 1]
       array[i][j - 1] = 0
       j -= 1
    elif (minCost == array[i - 1][j]+C0):
       StringA += xLine[i - 1]
       StringB += '-'
       array[i - 1][j]= 0
       i -= 1
```

One way to double check your algorithm is to compute the actual cost of the backtracking steps.  In your current implementation I would expect the backtracking cost to be greater than the cost you had calculated (because the backtracking is ignoring the costs).

Comment: Ah that wasn't quite it, but it did lead me to the eventual solution so Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, wasn't accounting for the cost of the move from cell to cell

Solution:

```
def stringBuilder(array, costBook, xLine, yLine):
  StringA, StringB = "", ""
  i, j = len(xLine), len(yLine)
  totalCost = array[i][j]
  while (i != 0 or j != 0):
    if (array[i][j] == array[i][j - 1] + int(costBook['-' + yLine[j - 1]])):
        StringA += '-'
        StringB += yLine[j - 1]
        array[i][j] = 0
        j -= 1
    elif (array[i][j] == array[i - 1][j] + int(costBook[xLine[i - 1] + '-'])):
        StringA += xLine[i - 1]
        StringB += '-'
        array[i][j] = 0
        i -= 1
    elif (array[i][j] == array[i - 1][j - 1] + int(costBook[xLine[i - 1] + yLine[j - 1]])):
        StringA += xLine[i - 1]
        StringB += yLine[j - 1]
        array[i][j] = 0
        i -= 1
        j -= 1
```